# Removing duplicate columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to parse data, but duplicate names under columns started appearing.
Code:

```
import pandas as pd

def parseData():
  countries = pd.read_csv('Int_Monthly_Visitor.csv')
  cols = [e.strip() for e in list(countries.columns)]
  regions = {
      'Others': cols[30:]
  }

  countries.rename(str.strip, axis='columns', inplace=True)

  regionlist = pd.DataFrame({'Columns': regions['Others'], 'Non-Null count': countries.loc[0:120, regions['Others']].count()})

  print(regionlist)

parseData()
```

Output:

```
                 Columns  Non-Null count
USA                  USA             121
Canada            Canada             121
Australia      Australia             121
New Zealand  New Zealand             121
Africa            Africa             121
```

Expected output:

```
Columns        Non-Null count
USA                       121
Canada                    121
Australia                 121
New Zealand               121
Africa                    121
```

Is there a solution to remove the duplicate names under columns?

Comment: Is the first `USA, Canada ...` series is a column or index? You can either drop it if it is a column, or try `reset_index(drop=True)` if it is indexes

Comment: Those `USA, Canada ...` series were taken from columns in a CSV file

Answer (score 0):

Since you're reading your dataframe from a .csv file, you can use [**`pandas.read_csv`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and define `usecols` argument as shown below :

```
countries = pd.read_csv('Int_Monthly_Visitor.csv', usecols=lambda c: not c.startswith('Unnamed:'))
```

##### `>>> print(countries)`

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, unfortunately it did not work for me